# Detect if an [ExecuteAlways] MonoBehavior is running during a Unity3D project save

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We have a Unity3D project where were have some editor/play mode scripts tagged with the attribute `[ExecuteAlways]` that help us with UI/UX work by automatically changing properties on attached GameObjects.

Our issue is that these scripts are called every time the project is loaded/saved, which means that any time a developer opens the project, or saves an unrelated file all our affected Prefabs/GameObjects get re-serialized by Unity, causing a large "spam" of unnecessary changes in source control.

We tried to work around this by detecting if we're in editor mode and the values serialized are not changed, but the issue is that we can't detect if we're saving:

- `Application.isEditor` seems to be false during save
- `UNITY_EDITOR` seems to be not defined
- despite Visual Studio being attached to Unity, none of the breakpoints are hit
- `Debug.Log()` calls don't seem to run during save

Is there a way to somehow detect whether our `[ExecuteAlways]` behaviors are run during save?